# How can I "sticky" a folder so it appears opposite to other "sticky" folders?

Tags: windows-7, windows, user-folders

I know that if i want to "sticky" a folder/file in a folder sorted by name, I can use a symbol like `_` at the start of the name so it'll appear at the top or bottom (depending if it's sorted ascending or descending).

However, what if I want to have a folder/file "stickied" in the opposite position, so where I have `_lib` and `_work` at the top and regardless of what folders/file names there are I have a temp folder at the very bottom? How can I "sticky" a folder so it appears opposite to other "sticky" folders?

Comment: Tried starting with a Z?

Comment: @jatuttle0 the problem with Z is what if i have a folder called Zend? sure t in temp comes after e but what if i have an apps folder, a comes before e

Comment: Tried starting with `}` or `~`?

Comment: @A.Loiseau `}` and `~` both appear at the top with `_`. i'm looking for something that will appear opposite of them, ie. if `_tmp` appears at the very top then this new folder should then appear at the very bottom, like what you would get if you reverse the name sort in a folder directory

Comment: Try non-breaking space (NBSP) as the first character: hold ALT and press 0160 on the numeric keypad. If Windows Explorer balks at entering it, enter it in Notepad and copy/paste into the filename.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik Unfortunately, because of Explorer's sort algorithm, all non-alphanumeric characters - including NBSP - go to the top, not the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the function that Explorer uses to sort things ([`StrCmpLogicalW`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb759947)) sorts "special" (i.e. non-alphanumeric) characters first. It also knows a lot about high-bit ASCII characters, so starting with an `é` would put the item next to things that start with a plain `e`.

However, it always sorts CJK characters after Roman-like ones. If you [enable keyboard Unicode entry](https://superuser.com/a/1024956/380318), you can easily enter something like U+999 (`ঙ`) with the numeric keypad. To get that character, I typed <kbd>+</kbd>, <kbd>9</kbd>, <kbd>9</kbd>, <kbd>9</kbd> on the keypad while holding <kbd>Alt</kbd>. An item that starts with that is "stickied" to the end of the listing.