# small omega in notepad/ notepad++ for autohotkey

Tags: notepad++, autohotkey, unicode, character-encoding

I am trying to write an Autohotkey using notepad++ (also tried with notepad) but turned out it was not possible in default settings. I looked on internet and learned that ISO 8859-7:2003 and UNICODE encoding has it and I changed notepad++ ->Encoding->Character set->Greek-> ISO 8859-7

But I a still not able to insert small omega.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: What font are you using? Does that font have a small omega?

Comment: SciTE4AutoHotkey is a pretty good editor if you're not set on using Notepad++.  If you're trying to use small omega in a string to display you can also reference it using `chr(0x3C9)` or to send it as a keystroke `{U+03C9}`

Answer (score 0):

different ways to send Unicode characters in AutoHotkey:

```
vText := Chr(0x3C9)
SendInput %vText%

SendInput {U+03C9}

WinGet, hWnd, ID, A
ControlGetFocus, vCtlClassNN, ahk_id %hWnd%
PostMessage, 0x102, 0x3C9, 1, %vCtlClassNN%, ahk_id %hWnd% ;WM_CHAR
```

Answer (score 0):

*This is the long way around, but it will also allow the typing of all Unicode characters "by hand".*

**Alt Codes**:

"Small Omega" can be typed using an Alt-code, if enabled in the Registry Editor:

> HKEY_CURRENT_USER > Control Panel > Input Method
>
> String Value: EnableHexNumpad
>
> Value Data: 1

(from "Ben N" in post [Windows 10 - Alt code results in wrong character](https://superuser.com/questions/1024948/windows-10-alt-code-results-in-wrong-character))

Then,

typing it through AHK is the same as by hand:

```
Send, {RAlt down}{NumpadAdd}{Numpad0}{Numpad3}c{Numpad9}{RAlt up}
```

However,

the script will not work for those without the EnableHexNumpad value in the Registry Editor enabled.

> I have also verified one of [vafylec](https://superuser.com/users/678182/vafylec)'s suggestions: `Send, {U+03c9}`