# Windows 10: Inputting alt codes that start with "8xxx"

Tags: windows-10, alt-code

I am trying to input alt codes beginning 8xxx (as mentioned here in https://www.keynotesupport.com/internet/special-characters-math-currency.shtml) into text interfaces/programs like WhatsApp Web and Notepad, but they have not been working. **I can use the basic 256 alt codes with no problem, based on the ones I've tried so far.**

I tried the registry workaround mentioned in 
"[Windows 10 - Alt code results in wrong character](https://superuser.com/questions/1024948/windows-10-alt-code-results-in-wrong-character)", but despite doing so, the 8xxx series of alt codes do not work (I'm getting random Chinese characters instead).

Further information: I have to converse in multiple languages, so I have the UK, US, Chinese/Mandarin, and Japanese keyboards enabled. Thus far, I only use the alt codes with the US keyboard, which corresponds to my physical keyboard layout.

Is there a way to enable the usage of alt codes starting with 8 in everyday typing? Thanks!

Comment: Do you have the Chinese keyboard enabled?  Are you able to type in any other alt codes, including the 256 boundary?  Please Edit the question and condense the Question text, using the Edit button to the left of your avatar.

Comment: The Windows app Character Map may help indicate which codes to use.  You can also copy specific characters to the clipboard if you just need one.

Comment: @ChristopherHostage, thank you for the prompt reply. :) I have edited the question, so it's hopefully shorter and more to-the-point. I have not tried the Character Map, and will give it a go if it's helpful. I am familiar with copying and pasting symbols, but am really hoping to learn a method where I can just input it in as necessary.

Comment: Interesting, it looks like it's gotten more complicated than the last time I looked at a similar problem.  I guess I was only looking in the low-ordinal set of characters that were easily typed in, or copying one-time characters needs for pasting.  Phi, supposedly Alt+0278 , puts out the number 8.  For characters like Alt+027F , it looks like the character code is in hex, but I can't type it in.  Hopefully someone else has seen this problem recently.  If you do find a reliable answer, please put it in below.