# keyboardproblem cannot insert email at

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts

Acer Aspire A517-51G-817F FHD i7    S/N:NXGSXEV0178410ABB53400;  12/18

last year suddenly the email-sign @ could not builded by AltGr q. I had to build a shortcut. Evere time I must use the shortcut and insert the sign. You know the process: you order a thing from a company, they demand the emaiö-adress and then to repeat it. For that I have a second shortcut with the complete adress, but in many cases the orderdocument refuses the insert. That is very embarassing, I asked in a lot of help-portals, but noone had a solution. If you know it I would be very thankful!!!!

Comment: Why `AltGr/q`? What's your input language & keyboard? `@` is usually on `Shift/2` or `Shift/'` for English keyboards. [ `"` is on the opposite one]

Comment: @Tetsujin - judging by the name this guy has a QWERTZ keyboard, where @ is by default on `Alt GR` + `Q`. Walter, check on the OS settings that your locale and keyboard layout are set correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you can type Alt+64 (64 as number while pressing Alt - which is the ascii code for @). So you will need 3 keys instead of 2, but it should work.

But as said by Peregrino69 check and set your locals first.
If they are correct and it still doesn't work, you might have got some malware that took over at least some functions of the keyboard. This cannot be excuded if the change happened without noticing a cause. Some usb devices can hide them. (look for Uwe Sieber's site for more info onthis)

Comment: First thanks for help. But please notice: The keyboard worked without bugs for years,. What I described came suddenly. - Your devices are realized by me: alt 64 no reaction, the keyboard is set on DEU. If I change it to ENG; same fault. I am more or less a computer layman. How can I open the OS (Operating System? Windows?)? What do you mean with locale, where do I find the keyboard layout?

Comment: There is "Regional settings and language" in the control panel. There you have also a means to chack and set the keyboard layout. But you say that "alt+64" doesn't work? That would be strange but also very meaningful.

Comment: You say it: my problem is strange. I asked often and often dozens of "experts", nobody had access to the "inner life" of windows and the hardware, which is responsible for using the keyboard.

Comment: I admit not to be an expert on this.  But I found this that could give you some path to come over the issue not getting result with ASCII codes. Just try it out.  https://superuser.com/questions/1024948/windows-10-alt-code-results-in-wrong-character

Comment: I'm fascinated how the devices expand in regions I cannot handle. Where do I find locale? P try it another week, than the tag may be closed and I must handle the problem like now. Thanks for all which wanted to help.