# Why are my Alt codes different from what is generally reported online?

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts, unicode, symbols, alt-code

I was attempting to type the symbol for DC (direct current), I still haven't found it but in the process I noticed that the codes found online generate something completely different on my computer. I am using a P-7811FX (Gateway) laptop that has a numerical keypad on the right. This may have to do with language settings but I don't remember messing with them or even how to navigate to the settings.

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>9393</kbd> is usually some variant of the letter (v) for most users.

I get the following:

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>9393</kbd> = ▒ (I have no idea what that is; looks kind of cool though but not DC symbol)

Comment: alt+155 = ¢ which is standard but alt+1179 = ¢ also results in cent symbol?

Comment: `ALT+9393 = is usually some variant of the letter (v) for most users`. this is incorrect. Most people will see a different character after typing Alt+9393. And the [DC symbol is `⎓`​](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_current), not `⒱`

Answer (score 2):

## TL;DR

The value is taken as decimal modulo 256. In code page 437 the code point *9393 mod 256 = 177* is ▒

You must use the hex numpad with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>+codepoint</kbd> to get the correct character

---

[Alt codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alt_code) are generally limited to [ANSI or OEM code pages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_code_page) only and **won't work for code points larger than 255**. A *few* apps do support larger values, which means <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>9393</kbd> will produce [U+24B1](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/24b1/index.htm) (*parenthesized latin small letter v* = ⒱) as expected (9393 = 0x24B1). Some other apps just throw away any digits after the third one. But by default in almost all applications if you input any larger values then **only the low byte of the real value is taken** as the code point, i.e. modulo 256

So pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>9393</kbd> will be equivalent to <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>177</kbd> because 9393 ≡ 177 (mod 256). When you run US Windows which uses [code page 437](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437) for the OEM code page then at code point 177 is [▒ which is a medium shade block drawing character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E2%96%92). Same for <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>1179</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>155</kbd> as 1179 ≡ 155 (mod 256), and ¢ is code point 155 in code page 437

To produce code point 9393 (U+24B1) reliably in any apps you need to use the hex numpad by creating a registry key named `EnableHexNumpad` with type `REG_SZ` in `HKCU\Control Panel\Input Method`, set its value to 1 then reboot. After that you can type the character as <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd> then <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Unicode value</kbd> (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>+24B1</kbd> in your case). If you use some applications with special Unicode input support like MS Word then there are other better ways to insert Unicode characters

For more information read

- [How to enter Unicode characters in Microsoft Windows](https://www.fileformat.info/tip/microsoft/enter_unicode.htm)
- [Insert ASCII or Unicode Latin-based symbols and characters](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/insert-ascii-or-unicode-latin-based-symbols-and-characters-d13f58d3-7bcb-44a7-a4d5-972ee12e50e0?ocmsassetID=HA010167539&CorrelationId=1ed32bc2-69ca-4bed-b751-4260640e7d09&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US)

But why do you think that ⒱ is the symbol for DC? The correct symbol for it is ⎓ [U+2393 (direct current symbol form two)](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2393/index.htm)​