# When using Alt+234 to type Ω (omega) on Windows 10, I actually get Û (UK keyboard)

Tags: windows-10, keyboard

According to many sources, to type the Ω symbol on Windows 10, you use Alt+234 (i.e. hold Alt and type 234 on the keypad). However, for me that produces a Û char (upper case u-circumflex).

I have a UK/GB keyboard.

How do I type an Ω symbol?

To enable alt codes, I added `EnableHexNumpad` string value to `Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Input Method` in the registry.

Edit: In Character Map on Windows 10, the alt code tip is not shown for the omega symbol.

[image: Windows 10 Character Map - Omega]

But, the alt code for µ (micro) is shown in Windows 10.

[image: Windows 10 Character Map - Micro]

Seems that Û (what I get when I type Alt+234) should actually be Alt+0219. So that's confusing.

[image: Windows 10 Character Map - U-circumflex]

Comment: Which app are typing it on? Try with Alt+969.

Comment: Chrome on Windows. Using Alt+969 produces the "╔" char. I have a UK keyboard if that's relevant.

Comment: Did you actually press the + on the numpad or did you only press alt followed by 969?

Comment: @Seth No, I am not pressing the + key (or shift and +), but I tried that out of curiosity and it had no effect (alt and 969 still types ╔ / alt and 234 types Û).

Comment: Alt code depends on locale, so avoid it unless you're in Greek locale. Just press `Windows+;` > Symbols > Language symbol. Duplicates: [How Can I Type A Checkmark (✓) Via Alt Code?](https://superuser.com/a/1666418/241386), [Why are my Alt codes different from what is generally reported online?](https://superuser.com/q/1451575/241386). Alt+hexcode would be usable but still difficult to remember

Comment: Ah, ok, UK keyboard... not much in the way of search results for "uk keyboard omega alt code" https://www.google.com/search?q=%2Buk+keyboard+omega+alt+code

Comment: It should be alt and +969 not just alt 969 but I guess you did try that. At least that's mentioned on sites that also mention EnableHexNumpad. The Wikipedia article on Unicode input also mentions that codes between 160 and 250 depend on code page/oem pages, lacking the use of the +. If you're on Windows using the "Emoji Keyboard" which you can bring up with Win + . might be an alternative. It does also feature a page for regular characters. It would be impractile to write a text though.

Comment: Oh, so using + (i.e. above the enter key on the numpad) does produce different chars, but not the one I was hoping for. Alt+234 produces "ȴ" and Alt+969 produces "+".

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the font, keyboard layout and application(?), I've found Ω can be typed by <kbd>Alt</kbd>+234, 0937 or 8486... or you might get yet another character, such as ♠. On this PC, at this moment, 234->Ω, 0937->©, 8486->& and 969->╔.  <sub>*sigh*</sub>

You might find [adding another keyboard layout](https://www.coolblue.nl/en/advice/change-layout-keyboard-windows-10.html), e.g., [United States - international keyboard](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/how-to-use-the-united-states-international-keyboard-layout-in-windows-7-in-windows-vista-and-in-windows-xp-e05ce3ed-11f0-8fc2-498e-a214fa6b898f) or [Greek (Ελληνικά)](https://www.ctsfw.edu/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/Greek-Unicode-Keyboard-Input-Windows-10.pdf), helpful. Keyboard layouts can be quickly switched, e.g., with <kbd>Windows</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd>, and use "dead keys" to type special characters.

Regrettably, omega, Ω, seems resistant to consistency. Mu, µ, is  more easily micro-managed.

Comment: Interesting idea to switch to US keyboard layout. I might try that.

Comment: "United States - international keyboard," not "United States keyboard". Or the Greek... see above.

Answer (score 0):

Press <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> and type `regedit` on the text box. It will ask you for privileges, accept. Then navigate to the key `HKEY_CURRENT_USER/Control Panel/Input Method`. Create a string value named `EnableHexNumpad` and set it to 1. Restart your PC.

You need the code point of the character you want to type (for Ω, 3A9). Hold <kbd>Alt</kbd>, press <kbd>+</kbd> on your Numpad and type your hex code on the numpad, typing letters on your keyboard as needed. Stop holding <kbd>Alt</kbd> when done, and voila, you have your Ω!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the code page used by your program; Windows, by default utilize ANSI for all programs and advanced programs uses Unicode.  ANSI do not have a character for Ω but the 437 (US) codepage for ASCII does and is 234.

On code page 850 (Western European DOS) the code 234 is Û

Seems your program is using ASCII codes, and the extended codepage 850, look if your program can use UNICODE and input the symbol as 0x03A9 also you can use Windows Char Map to copy and paste, but if your app do not support UNICODE the symbol can not be pasted.  Also you can look if your software do support extended codepage 437.

More information on:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_input