# Entering Unicode character using Alt-Numpad, in decimal

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, unicode, input-languages, global

On a PC keyboard (Windows), is there a method, without having to install additional software, to enter any Unicode character using its code point in decimal?

`Alt` `+` `abcd` does it in hexadecimal, but I am looking for a method for decimals. Hexadecimals require using keys outside the number pad, and a combination of some letters with Alt key may cause unintended side effects. For example, `Alt-F` in notepad will open the File menu making it impossible to enter the hexadecimal `f` character.

Comment: This is most likely not possible. I have also searched for such solutions because I have the same problems. I have programmed symbols into my keyboard firmware and have implemented this with Alt+Unicode codepoint entering because that felt like the most portable solution. I ended up opening "Run as" with Win+R, type it there, select and copy and paste it wherever I need it. Not really practical and slow. Think I will switch to WinCompose or something like that and just not use these symbols on foreign machines. https://superuser.com/a/864971/389874 hints that there is no solution for this.

Answer (score 1):

In Windows, there is now a built-in method to enter any Unicode character using its code point in hexadecimal, if you have WordPad (comes out of the box) or the new Notepad in Windows 11.

In Word or the new Notepad, simply type in the code point in hexadecimal, eg `1f354`. Then, without moving your cursor, press `Alt-X`, and the characters you've typed will be replaced with the Unicode character. You can then copy and paste it to where you need it. Still a bit cumbersome, but it works.

Comment: The Microsoft article about that: [Insert ASCII or Unicode Latin-based symbols and characters - Microsoft Support](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/insert-ascii-or-unicode-latin-based-symbols-and-characters-d13f58d3-7bcb-44a7-a4d5-972ee12e50e0 "Insert ASCII or Unicode Latin-based symbols and characters - Microsoft Support").